# break dataframe into subsets by factor values, send to function that returns glm class, how to recombine?

Tags: r, plyr

Thanks to Hadley's plyr package ddply function we can take a dataframe, break it down into subdataframes by factors, send each to a function, and then combine the function results for each subdataframe into a new dataframe.

But what if the function returns an object of a class like glm or in my case, a c("glm", "lm"). Then, these can't be combined into a dataframe can they? I get this error instead

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class 'c("glm", "lm")' into a data.frame
```

Is there some more flexible data structure that will accommodate all the complex glm class results of my function calls, preserving the information regarding the dataframe subsets?

Or should this be done in an entirely different way?

Comment: Did you try `dlply`? Output is a list.

Comment: You're right, thanks, dlply works. The hierarchical list that comes back is something I'm not familiar with and I don't know if I can reassign back to the dataframe structure in some scalable way, but it's probably just a matter of me understanding list slicing and such better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to expand my comment: `plyr` has set of functions to combine input and output type. So when you function returns something inconvertible to `data.frame` you should use `list` as output. So instead of using `ddply` use `dlply`.

When you want to do something on each model and convert results to `data.frame` then `ldply` is the key.

Lets create some models using `dlply`

```
list_of_models <- dlply(warpbreaks, .(tension), function(X) lm(breaks~wool, data=X))
str(list_of_models, 1)
# List of 3
#  $ L:List of 13
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
#  $ M:List of 13
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
#  $ H:List of 13
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
#  - attr(*, "split_type")= chr "data.frame"
#  - attr(*, "split_labels")='data.frame':        3 obs. of  1 variable:
```

It gives `list` of three `lm` models.

Using `ldply` you could create a `data.frame`, e.g.

- with predictions of each model:

  ```
  ldply(list_of_models, function(model) {
      data.frame(fit=predict(model, warpbreaks))
  })
  #     tension     fit
  # 1         L 44.5556
  # 2         L 44.5556
  # 3         L 44.5556
  ```
- with statistics to each model:

  ```
  ldply(list_of_models, function(model) {
    c(
      aic = extractAIC(model),
      deviance = deviance(model),
      logLik = logLik(model),
      confint = confint(model),
      coef = coef(model)
    )
  })
  # tension aic1    aic2 deviance   logLik confint1  confint2 confint3 confint4 coef.(Intercept) coef.woolB
  # 1       L    2 98.3291  3397.78 -72.7054  34.2580 -30.89623  54.8531 -1.77044          44.5556  -16.33333
  # 2       M    2 81.1948  1311.56 -64.1383  17.6022  -4.27003  30.3978 13.82559          24.0000    4.77778
  # 3       H    2 76.9457  1035.78 -62.0137  18.8701 -13.81829  30.2411  2.26273          24.5556   -5.77778
  ```